# Why am I getting “error stdin: is not a tty, /my/local/directory: no such file or directory”?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp

I can't figure out why it can't find my directory. I am using the SSH terminal in cPanel to transfer a large directory to my remote server from the local machine I'm on. I ran

```
scp -r C:/my/local/directory root@my.ip.addr:/my/remote/directory
```

I've also tried without the -r with just a file and the same error occured. I am typing in the password to the server when it asks but it also asks for a passphrase I do not have access to. I just skip it and it asks me for the password. At the end it says connection to C closed, so I know it's recognizing that. Would it be easier to use FTP? I'm pretty new to linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`scp` interprets `:` as a separator between `host` and `path`. On windows, you can't user absolute path with `scp`. Rather use relative paths:

```
cd C:/my/local
scp -r directory/ root@my.ip.addr:/my/remote/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to your home directory / path using the attilde (`~`) symbol. So if my folder already resides within the home directory of the current user from which I'm trying to copy, I can do something like:

```
scp -r ~/dir123 aphorise@remote.fqdn.com:~/.
```

This would copy `dir123` from current loged users home directory (typically in `/home/user_id`) onto the remote users home directory with the same name & similarly within the root of their `home` directory.